# Unable to get document data in firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to access data from a firestore document, but I'm getting an error message that `exercise.data() is not a function`. I don't understand how the `exercisesToAdd` array is an array of documents, but I can't use `.data()` to get the contents of the items? How else would I go about getting the data from those documents?

I know the `exercisesToAdd` array is actually being filled with documents because I see them in the database when I send the array. Seems straight-forward but I must be missing something.

```
chosenExercises.forEach((exercise) => {
    exercisesToAdd.push(doc(db, 'Users/' + auth.currentUser.uid + '/Exercises/' + exercise));
});

exercisesToAdd.forEach((exercise) => {
    console.log(exercise.data());
});
```

Comment: what is the doc function??

Comment: have you logged what exercisesToAdd is? Is it a list of promises?

Comment: Your code hasn't actually performed any queries, so there is no document data available.  Please review the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_a_document) and use `get()` to execute each document query first before calling `data()` on anything.  All `doc()` does is create a DocumentReference, which doesn't contain any data.

Comment: @DougStevenson This worked, thank you! I used `getDoc(exercise).then` to log `doc.data()`

Answer (score 1):

As [@Doug Stevenson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/807126/doug-stevenson) stated in his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73093375/unable-to-get-document-data-in-firestore#comment129094325_73093375):

> Your code hasn't actually performed any queries, so there is no document data available. Please review the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_a_document) and use `get()` to execute each document query first before calling `data()` on anything. All `doc()` does is create a DocumentReference, which doesn't contain any data.